# Location depedency error for PlatformLocation

Tags: javascript, jasmine, angular

I have my AppComponent which pulls in Location (from angular2/router) as a dependency.  Within the AppComponent, I'm calling Location.path().  In my Jasmine test, I'm seeing the following error.  What is wrong with my Jasmine test?  How do I setup the dependencies?

Stacktrace:

```
Error: EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of PlatformLocation! (Location -> LocationStrategy -> PlatformLocation).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLocation' of null
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLocation' of null
    at BrowserPlatformLocation._init (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js:2252:41)
    at new BrowserPlatformLocation (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js:2249:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:1519:20
    at Injector._instantiate (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11127:19)
    at Injector._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11069:21)
    at Injector._new (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11059:19)
    at InjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:10937:42)
    at Injector._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11260:33)
    at Injector._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11214:21)
    at Injector._getByDependency (http://localhost:3000/libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11202:21)
```

AppComponent Spec:

```
import {describe, it, expect, beforeEach, afterEach, beforeEachProviders, MockApplicationRef} from "angular2/testing";

import {provide, Injector, ApplicationRef} from "angular2/core";
import {XHRBackend, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {MockConnection, MockBackend} from "angular2/src/http/backends/mock_backend";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";

import {TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS, TranslateService} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";

import {AppComponent} from "./AppComponent";


describe("AppComponent", () => {
    let injector: Injector;
    let translateService: TranslateService;
    let app: AppComponent;
    let location: Location;

    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useClass: MockPrimaryComponent}),
        provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: "/"}),
        provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
        Location,
        provide(ApplicationRef, {useClass: MockApplicationRef})
    ]);

    beforeEach(() => {
        injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            Location,
            TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
            TranslateService

        ]);

        location = injector.get(Location);

        translateService = injector.get(TranslateService);

        app = new AppComponent(translateService, location);
    });
```

Comment: See how they do it in their [specs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f9fb72fb0e9bcbda7aeebbf8321ce5d70d78ecee/modules/angular2/test/router/integration/util.ts#L52)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out.  First, I had to import the `SpyLocation` object, and then adjust my references.  Working code below.

```
import {describe, it, expect, beforeEach, afterEach, beforeEachProviders, MockApplicationRef} from "angular2/testing";

import {provide, Injector, ApplicationRef} from "angular2/core";
import {XHRBackend, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {MockConnection, MockBackend} from "angular2/src/http/backends/mock_backend";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {SpyLocation} from "angular2/src/mock/location_mock";

import {TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS, TranslateService} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";

import {AppComponent} from "./AppComponent";


describe("AppComponent", () => {
    let injector: Injector;
    let translateService: TranslateService;
    let app: AppComponent;
    let location: SpyLocation;

    beforeEach(() => {
        injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            // Location,
            provide(Location, {useClass: SpyLocation}),
            TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
            TranslateService
        ]);

        location = injector.get(Location);

        translateService = injector.get(TranslateService);

        app = new AppComponent(translateService, location);
    });
```